# How to setup Backand real time communication is a Ionic2 app?

Tags: ionic2, backand

I can't find any example on how to do this.

Thanks,

Guillaume

Answer (score 0):

[This one](https://github.com/backand/YoutubeIonic) is for ionic, its broadcasting what the user sees on his device youtube app to a desktop browser